# How can I use base_path() inside a view in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I have the following fields inside a view:

1. User ID
2. Teaser

   - I selected "*exclude from display*" for the **User ID** field.
   - In the **Teaser** field, I selected the "*rewrite the output of this field*" option. This way, I can use html to completely control the structure of the view's output. Moreover, I can call the User ID field by using it's token, **[uid]**.

For example, I can do the following in the teaser's rewrite:

> ```
> <a href="user/[uid]" title="Visit this user's profile">Visit Profile</a>
> ```

The problem with the above code is that the path is relative. It will only work on the front page of the site.

For example, if this link is clicked in

> www.example.com/node/1

then it will visit a non-existent URL of:

> node/1/user/[uid]

I have tried the following: http://chopapp.com/#o7osql65

But views fields does not allow PHP codes.

I might be approaching this entirely wrong. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to rewrite the output of the UID field, and have it be rendered as a link.  Even if you exclude it from display initially, it will still be available as a link via its token to other fields.  One of the options when selecting to 'output this field as a link' is to make the link absolute.

Comment: Hi Will, Thanks for the reply. Per your suggestion, I have done the following: 

1. Selected "_Output this field as a link_" for the User ID field. 
2. Included "user/[uid]" in the "_Link Path_".

The output now is something like this:

`<a href="absolute-url-to-node">1</a>`

The only problem is that I would like to replace the uid (1 in this case) to another token. For example, I have allowed my users to submit "Full Name" (custom cck field). Therefore I would like the links to appear like this:


`<a href="absolute-url-to-node">[user_fullname_token]</a>`


Any idea?

Comment: Well just add the `Full name` field and make sure it's positioned before the field which output you are trying to rewrite and exclude it from the display. Just place it first or something, you don't want to show this field, just need the token to use it. After this you should have a token for the user's `Full name`. If it's a cck field the token will start with the `field_`prefix, something like this: `field_full_name` (depending on what's the machine name)